# Worm indicator not drawn properly in custom Bottom Navigation Bar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to add a worm indicator below bottom bar item using item offset but its not drawn properly. Not able to figure out what calculations are wrong!

**Current Result**:

[image]

**Required Result**:

[image]

Here is full implementation(Issue is in last 2 sample codes, rest composables are for better understanding):

`Sample navigation data:`

```
sealed class MainNavigation(
    val title: String,
    val route: String,
    val icon: ImageVector
) {
    data object ScreenA : MainNavigation(
        title = "Screen1",
        route = "Screen1",
        icon = Icons.Default.Home
    )

    data object ScreenB : MainNavigation(
        title = "Screen2",
        route = "Screen2",
        icon = Icons.Default.Notifications
    )

    data object ScreenC : MainNavigation(
        title = "Screen3",
        route = "Screen3",
        icon = Icons.Default.Favorite
    )

    data object ScreenD : MainNavigation(
        title = "Screen4",
        route = "Screen4",
        icon = Icons.Default.Email
    )
}
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
val navigationItems = MainNavigation::class.nestedClasses.map {
it.objectInstance as MainNavigation
}
var selectedItem by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

Scaffold(
    bottomBar = {
        AnimatedBottomBar(
            selectedItem = selectedItem,
            itemSize = navigationItems.size,
            indicatorStyle = IndicatorStyle.DOT,
            containerColor = Color.Transparent,
            indicatorColor = Color.Red
        ) {
            navigationItems.forEachIndexed { index, navigationItem ->
                BottomBarItem(
                    selected = currentRoute == navigationItem.route,
                    onClick = {
                        if (currentRoute != navigationItem.route) {
                            selectedItem = index
                            ...
                        }
                    },
                    imageVector = navigationItem.icon,
                    label = navigationItem.title,
                    containerColor = Color.Transparent
                )
            }
        }
    }
    ) {
        NavHost(
            navController = navController,
            startDestination = MainNavigation.ScreenA.route
        ) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

`AnimatedBottomBar`

```
@Composable
fun AnimatedBottomBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    bottomBarHeight: Dp = 64.dp,
    containerColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer,
    contentColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
    selectedItem: Int? = null,
    itemSize: Int? = null,
    indicatorStyle: IndicatorStyle = IndicatorStyle.NONE,
    indicatorColor: Color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onPrimaryContainer,
    indicatorHeight: Dp = DEFAULT_INDICATOR_HEIGHT,
    animationSpec: AnimationSpec<Dp> = spring(
        dampingRatio = 1f,
        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessMediumLow
    ),
    indicatorDirection: IndicatorDirection = IndicatorDirection.TOP,
    indicatorShape: RoundedCornerShape = RoundedCornerShape(25.dp),
    content: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        color = containerColor,
        contentColor = contentColor,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        BoxWithConstraints(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = Dp(bottomBarHeight / (bottomBarHeight / 16)))
        ) {
            selectedItem?.let {
                itemSize?.let {
                    val maxWidth = this.maxWidth
                    val indicatorOffset: Dp by animateDpAsState(
                        targetValue = (maxWidth / itemSize) * selectedItem,
                        animationSpec = animationSpec,
                        label = "indicator"
                    )

                    DotIndicator(
                        indicatorOffset = indicatorOffset,
                        arraySize = itemSize,
                        indicatorColor = indicatorColor,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .height(bottomBarHeight),
                        selectedItem = selectedItem
                    )
                }
            }

            Row(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(bottomBarHeight)
                    .selectableGroup(),
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween,
                content = content
            )
        }
    }
}
```

`Composable with possible issue`

```
@Composable
internal fun DotIndicator(
    indicatorOffset: Dp,
    arraySize: Int,
    indicatorColor: Color,
    modifier: Modifier,
    selectedItem: Int
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(1f / arraySize)
    ) {
        Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)) {
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .customWormTransition(indicatorOffset, indicatorColor, selectedItem)
                .size(8.dp))
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(4.dp))
        }
    }
}


fun Modifier.customWormTransition(
    offset: Dp,
    indicatorColor: Color,
    selectedItem: Int,
) = composed {
    drawWithContent {
        val distance = size.width + 10.dp.roundToPx()
        val scrollPosition = selectedItem + (offset.toPx().div(distance))
        val wormOffset = (scrollPosition % 1) * 2

        val xPos = scrollPosition.toInt() * distance
        val head = xPos + distance * 0f.coerceAtLeast(wormOffset - 1)
        val tail = xPos + size.width + 1f.coerceAtMost(wormOffset) * distance

        val worm = RoundRect(
            head, 0f, tail, size.height,
            CornerRadius(50f)
        )

        val path = Path().apply { addRoundRect(worm) }

        // Draw the original content
        drawContent()

        // Draw the worm shape on top of the content
        drawPath(path = path, color = indicatorColor)
    }
}
```

I tried many calculation changes but many times, indicator won't even show up.

Comment: I tried to make `customWormTransition` by referring this article, but it uses pager state: https://blog.canopas.com/jetpack-compose-how-to-implement-custom-pager-indicators-8b6a01d63964#:~:text=Worm%20Dot%20indicator,-For%20this%20indicator&text=We%20just%20need%20to%20change,create%20a%20modifier%20for%20it.&text=Here%20we%20have%20calculated%20the,the%20path%20in%20drawBehind%20modifier.